Observable data lost on API call
so I am using Spartacus as the base of the project. In spartacus the data for the product is caught with this search method:
search(query: string | undefined, searchConfig?: SearchConfig): void {
  if (query) {
    this.store.dispatch(
      new ProductActions.SearchProducts({
        queryText: query,
        searchConfig: searchConfig,
      })
    );
  }
}

Now all of this is data is passed to the model$ Observable. In my project I have to implement show more which keeps the display of previous items and displays new items. When I call the function:
getPageItems(pageNumber: number): void {
  this.routing
    .getRouterState()
    .subscribe((route) => {
      const routeCriteria = this.getCriteriaFromRoute(
        route.state.params,
        route.state.queryParams
      );
      const criteria = {
        ...routeCriteria,
        currentPage: pageNumber,
      };
      this.search(criteria);
    })
    .unsubscribe();
}

This updates the entire observable and I lose the previous product items. How can I keep track of the previous product items and push new product items?

In your reducer, you would need to append the new search results to the existing list.
Right now, your reducer probably has something like this:
on(ProductActions.SearchProductsSuccess, (state, action) => ({
   ...state,
   searchResults: action.searchResults
}))

To append new search results, try this instead:
on(ProductActions.SearchProductsSuccess, (state, action) => ({
   ...state,
   searchResults: [...state.searchResults, ...action.searchResults]
}))

If you can't modify the reducer and can only work within the component, you can save the emissions from the model$ observable to a new variable in the component:
// Define the variable at the top of your component
searchResults: any[] = [];

// Then, where ever you subscribe to model$, push the new search results to the array.
model$.subscribe((results) => {
   this.searchResults.push(results);
});

You will have to refactor your component to show the results from the searchResults array instead of model$.

I don't have access to reducers or any data manipulation. These functions are finished and available Spartacus functions. I only have an access to the Observable through already existing Spartacus services. That's why I'm looking for a way to create a functionality on the component level that would concat new observable data to the existing one on a each API call. I don't want to overwrite existing services if not needed

Hi @Skafec , I added an update to my answer, where I detail how you can push the results from an observable emission onto a component-level variable. Hope that helps!

First, why do you call .unsubscribe immediately? You have to save your subscribe function result and call unsubscribe on it on component destroy (ngOnDestroy) or use advanced techniques such as takeUntil or even custom decorators.
Second, in a place where you listen your ProductActions.SearchProducts action, you probably emit something like  ProductActions.SearchProductsSuccess with a new data. This action you are processing in your reducers. So, in your reducers you have to return new state as a result of prev state plus new data like this:
case ProductActions.SearchProductsSuccess: {
    return state.concat(action.data.products);
}



These are not my function. That's how core Spartacus is done. And I don't have access to this or how the API data is manipulated. I only have an Observable that I can get from the already implemented Spartacus services. That's why I need a smart way to store Observable data on the component (or a service) and contact it to the previous result
